# Want to pass json object to php from angular JS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Here is my JSON

```
Data: {
    "JobExp": [{
        "PostingDate": "2016/01/22",
        "Role": "Software Developer",
        "id": 0,
        "$$hashKey": "object:4"
    }],
    "no_job_post": 1
}
```

I want to pass this to a php file and I doing like this

```
var json_data=JSON.stringify($scope.CreateJob);

var input_data=$.param({
            json:json_data
        });

console.log("Data: "+json_data);

       $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : 'save_job.php',
            data    : input_data,
            headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        })
        .success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }).error(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
```

The above console showing me the json as shown above

But PHP shows me blank.
Am I doing right ?

Comment: How you are receiving this in PHP? Post that also..

Comment: <?php
 
 include "../../../config_i.php";
 
 $json_data=$_POST['json'];
 $job_data=json_decode($json_data,true);
 
 echo $json_data;
 
 /*foreach($job_data['JobExp'] as $job)
 {
  $sql_query = "insert into mdl_job_postings(role) values('".$job_data['Role']."')";
  mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);
 }*/

 
?>

Comment: Did you check input_data whether it is returning any value?

Comment: Yes it is returning me the JSON as shown

Comment: Has 'save_job.php' string ` echo $_POST;` ?

Comment: Yes it has infact the above php code has the echo

Comment: Error solved ..I was not parsing the JSON data properly...unwanted slashes were there in the JSON data..I removed those..Thank you